# Finding the latest file in a directory with specific filename format

Tags: excel

I need a VBA code to find the latest file in a directory with specific filename - the name format is like this : BalanceValidation2021-06-01_2021-05-31_13-25, where the part from the name that matters is : "BalanceValidation2021-06-01_2021". The file path is C:\Schedules\PS.
Can you help with that, please?
Here's my code, but i don't know how to search for the specific part in the filename :

```
Sub Most_recent_file_open()
Dim myFile As String, myRecentFile As String, myMostRecentFile As String
Dim recentDate As Date
Dim myDirectory As String
myDirectory = "C:\Users\rvasil01\Desktop\Raychi files\PD\Schedules\PS\"
Dim fileExtension As String
fileExtension = “ * .xlsx”

If Right(myDirectory, 1) <> "\" Then myDirectory = myDirectory & "\"

'myFile = Dir(myDirectory & fileExtension, 0)
myFile = Dir(myDirectory & fileExtension)
'MsgBox myFile
If myFile <> "" Then
    myRecentFile = myFile
    recentDate = FileDateTime(myDirectory & myFile)
    Do While myFile <> ""
        If FileDateTime(myDirectory & myFile) > recentDate Then
             myRecentFile = myFile
             recentDate = FileDateTime(myDirectory & myFile)
         End If
         myFile = Dir
    Loop
End If
myMostRecentFile = myRecentFile
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myDirectory & myMostRecentFile

End Sub
```

Comment: @JvdV yes, thank you i forgot to post the code, sorry.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific **format**?  or are you looking for the **contents** contains or starts-with `BalanceValidation2021-06-01_2021`?  If you are looking for a **format**, what parts of the string example can be variable, and how might they vary?